# Find files which size is greather or equal X

Tags: linux, unix, find

How can I find files larger than or small than or same size as another file `X` using the `find(1)` command, without `awk(1)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you're doing this on linux:

Same size as another file:

```
$ find . -size `stat --printf '%s' $other_file`c
```

Larger than another file:

```
$ find . -size +`stat --printf '%s' $other_file`c
```

Smaller:

```
$ find . -size -`stat --printf '%s' $other_file`c
```

Answer (score 0):

`find(1)` doesn't have a direct file size comparison tool, as it does for comparing file atime, mtime, or ctime with a reference file.

What you can do that is similar is retrieve the size of the reference file before calling `find(1)`:

```
find . -type f -size -$(stat -c %s /etc/passwd)c -ls # smaller than /etc/passwd
find . -type f -size +$(stat -c %s /etc/passwd)c -ls # larger than /etc/passwd
find . -type f -size $(stat -c %s /etc/passwd)c -ls # same size as /etc/passwd
```